# SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Tags: android, http

this error is really really really strange and I don't know how to reproduce it and how to fix it because I made a lot of searches but nothing was useful.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Stack Trace
_________________________________
0   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
1       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
2       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
3       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
4       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
5       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
6       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
7       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
8       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
9   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
10      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:430)
11      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
13      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
14      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
15      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
16      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
17      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
18      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
19      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
20      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
21      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
22      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
23      at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
24      at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:185)
25      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
26      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.sendRequestJSON(MusixMatchApi.java:1143)
27      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.handleRequestJSON(MusixMatchApi.java:982)
28      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.getConfig(MusixMatchApi.java:211)
29      at com.designfuture.music.asynctask.GetConfigAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetConfigAsyncTask.java:28)
30      at com.designfuture.music.asynctask.GetConfigAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetConfigAsyncTask.java:1)
31      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
32      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
33      ... 4 more
34  Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
35      at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
36      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
37      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
38      ... 26 more
39  Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
40      ... 29 more
41  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
42      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:430)
43      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
44      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
45      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
46      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
47      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
48      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
49      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
50      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
51      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
52      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
53      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
54      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
55      at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
56      at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:185)
57      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
58      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.sendRequestJSON(MusixMatchApi.java:1143)
59      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.handleRequestJSON(MusixMatchApi.java:982)
60      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.getConfig(MusixMatchApi.java:211)
61      at com.designfuture.music.asynctask.GetConfigAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetConfigAsyncTask.java:28)
62      at com.designfuture.music.asynctask.GetConfigAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetConfigAsyncTask.java:1)
63      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
64      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
65      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
66      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
67      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
68      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
69  Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
70      at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
71      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
72      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
73      ... 26 more
74  Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
75      ... 29 more
76  libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
77      at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
78      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
79      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
80      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
81      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
82      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
83      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
84      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
85      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
86      at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
87      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
88      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
89      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
90      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
91      at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
92      at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
93      at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:185)
94      at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
95      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.sendRequestJSON(MusixMatchApi.java:1143)
96      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.handleRequestJSON(MusixMatchApi.java:982)
97      at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.getConfig(MusixMatchApi.java:211)
98      at com.designfuture.music.asynctask.GetConfigAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetConfigAsyncTask.java:28)
99      at com.designfuture.music.asynctask.GetConfigAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetConfigAsyncTask.java:1)
100     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
101     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
102     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
103     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
104     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
105     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
106 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
107     ... 29 more
108 libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
109     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
110     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
111     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
112     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
113     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
114     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
115     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
116     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
117     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
118     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
119     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
120     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
121     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
122     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
123     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
124     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
125     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:185)
126     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
127     at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.sendRequestJSON(MusixMatchApi.java:1143)
128     at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.handleRequestJSON(MusixMatchApi.java:982)
129     at com.designfuture.music.api.MusixMatchApi.getConfig(MusixMatchApi.java:211)
130     at com.designfuture.music.asynctask.GetConfigAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetConfigAsyncTask.java:28)
131     at com.designfuture.music.asynctask.GetConfigAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetConfigAsyncTask.java:1)
132     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
133     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
134     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
135     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
136     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
137     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my_app_package"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="my_version_code"
    android:versionName="my_version_name" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mxm_icon"
        android:label="@string/musicbrowserlabel"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Music" >

        <!-- MY ACTIVITIES -->



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please don't bother asking me if I have the correct INTERNET permission in my manifest because this app is in market since 2 years :P

I've also noticed that (from Crittercism) all bugs are coming from Android 4.1.x version (JB). I don't know if device are rooted or what (I can't see this information for the moment)

Comment: is it possible that the hostname has changed (because of this error message): No address associated with hostname

Comment: did you tried with different versions of device? or getting on each version?

Comment: plz add
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


Outside < Application> tag 
Please rebuild your project and run. its worked for me

Comment: By the way order matters, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135595/permission-denied-missing-internet-permission-but-permission-is-given

Comment: @SteErMi  have you resolved this issue , I am facing the same situation

Answer (score 131, accepted):

***NOTE: I wrote this answer in Jun 2013, so it's bit dated nowadays. Many things changed in Android platform since version 6 (Marshmallow, released late 2015), making the whole problem more/less obsolete. However I believe this post can still be worth reading as general problem analysis approach example.***

---

Exception you are getting (`SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)`), clearly indicates that you are not allowed to do networking. That's pretty indisputable fact. But how can this happen? Usually it's either due to missing `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` entry in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file or, as internet permission is granted at installation time.

**My Manifest is correct, so how can this happen?**

Theoretically, presence of `uses-permission` in Manifest perfectly fulfills the requirement and from developer standpoint is all that's needed to be done to be able to do networking. Moreover, since permissions are shown to the user during installation, the fact your app ended installed on user's device means s/he granted what you asked for (otherwise installation is cancelled), so assumption that if your code is executed then all requested permissions are granted is valid. And once granted, user cannot revoke the permission other way than uninstalling the app completely as standard Android framework (from AOSP) offers no such feature at the moment.

But things are getting more tricky if you also do not mind your app running on [rooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting) devices too. There're tools available in Google Play your users can install to control permission granted to installed apps **at run-time** - for example: [Permissions Denied](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stericson.permissions.donate) and others. This can also be done with [CyanogenMod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod), vendor brand (i.e. LG's) or [other custom ROM](http://lifehacker.com/this-database-of-android-roms-helps-you-choose-the-best-1449794780), featuring various type of "privacy managers" or similar tools.

So if app is blocked either way, it's basically blocked intentionally by the user and if so, it is really more user problem in this case (or s/he do not understand what certain options/tools really do and what would be the consequences) than yours, because standard SDK (and most apps are written with that SDK in mind) simply does not behave that way. So I **strongly** doubt this problem occurs on "standard", non-rooted device with stock (or vendor like Samsung, HTC, Sony etc) ROM.

**I do not want to crash...**

Properly implemented permission management and/org blocking must deal with the fact that most apps may not be ready for the situation where access to certain features is both granted and not accessible at the same time, as this is kind of contradiction where app uses manifest to request access at install time. Access control done right should must make all things work as before, and still limit usability using techniques in scope of expected behavior of the feature. For example, when certain permission is granted (i.e. GPS, Internet access) such feature can be made available from the app/user perspective (i.e. you can turn GPS on. or try to connect), the altered implementation can provide no real data - i.e. GPS can always return no coordinates, like when you are indoor or have no satellite "fix". Internet access can be granted as before, but you can make no successful connection as there's no data coverage or routing. Such scenarios should be expected in normal usage as well, therefore it should be handled by the apps already. As this simply can happen during normal every day usage, any crash in such situation should be most likely  be related to application bugs.

We lack too much information about the environment on which this problem occurs to diagnose problem w/o guessing, but as kind of solution, you may consider using [setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) to catch such unexpected exceptions in future and i.e. simply show user detailed information what permission your app needs instead of just crashing. Please note that using this will most likely conflict with tools like Crittercism, ACRA and others, so be careful if you use any of these.

**Notes**

Please be aware that `android.permission.INTERNET` is not the only networking related permission you may need to declare in manifest in attempt to successfully do networking. Having `INTERNET` permission granted simply allows applications to open network sockets (which is basically fundamental requirement to do any network data transfer). But in case your network stack/library would like to get information about networks as well, then you will also need `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` in your Manifest (which is i.e. required by [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) client ([see tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)).

---

**Addendum (2015-07-16)**

Please note that Android 6 (aka Marshmallow) introduced completely new permission management mechanism called **Runtime Permissions**. It gives user more control on what permission are granted (also allows selective grant) or lets one revoke already granted permissions w/o need to app removal:

> This [...] introduces a new permissions model, where users can now
> directly manage app permissions at runtime. This model gives users
> improved visibility and control over permissions, while streamlining
> the installation and auto-update processes for app developers. Users
> can grant or revoke permissions individually for installed apps.

However, the changes do not affect `INTERNET` or `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permissions, which are considered "Normal" permissions. The user does not need to explicitly grant these permission.

See [behavior changes description](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html) page for details and make sure your app will behave correctly on newer systems too. It's is especially important when your project set `targetSdk` to at least `23` as then you **must** support new  permissions model ([detailed documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)). If you are not ready, ensure you keep `targetSdk` to at most `22` as this ensures even new Android will use old permission system when your app is installed.

Comment: Upvoted this answer to undo the downvote from somebody else. At first I thought that you indeed didn't read the entire question and just wanted to be fast (by the way, your answer really WAS too short at first ;-)), but I think the remark about users (on rooted devices) being able to thwart your permission requests was a good one.

Comment: Mmmm so if this is from rooted user that are removing permissions I've 2 questions: 1) how can I know if I've not that permission? 2) How can I ask it again? (still, I don't know if we're talking about this kind of problem)

Comment: You cannot ask for it again, because this permission is not granted at runtime. See edited answer for possible "solution"

Comment: Same here: i was about to downgrade but the second part of the anwswer  seems to be the part that worth reading :) you should remove first lines of the answers as StErMi clearly showed that he had set INTERNET permission.

Comment: You also need    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 63):

Be sure that the place where you adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

is right.

You should write it like that in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project"> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Dont make my mistakes :)

Answer (score 34):

Android Studio 1.3b1 (not sure about other versions) autocompleted my internet permission to `ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET`.  Changing it to `android.permission.INTERNET` fixed the issue.

Comment: This should now be fixed in Android Studio 1.4 RC 1 (currently in the Canary channel).

Comment: I had a case issue too. Instead of android.permission.INTERNET it was android.permission.internet in my manifest file

Answer (score 32):

Add to manifest file the line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

It fixed it for me.

Answer (score 21):

Write your permission before the application tag as given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.someapp.sample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: This was actually the only thing that helped me :( Not intuitive at all.

Answer (score 20):

I resolved this error, I was adding permissions inside Application tag by mistake. I putted outside and it works fine. Hope it helps for someone.

Answer (score 17):

I also had this problem. it was weird that it worked on my lollipop emulator, but not on my actual kitkat device.

Android Studio will now force you to write the permission upper case, and that's the problem.

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Above the  application tab and it will work.

Comment: This is the simple and correct answer. And should be the one on top!

Answer (score 4):

Put these permission outside the `<application>` tag preferable before the tag, I tried it and it works for me.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

if it was an IPv6 address, have a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33046

Looks like there was a bug in Android that was fixed in 4.3(?).

Answer (score 2):

Just like Tom mentioned. When you start with capital `A` then autocomplete will complete it as.

```
ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET
```

When you start typing with `a` then autocomplete will complete it as

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

The second one is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I spend hours looking for solution to this problem and none of the solution in the answers worked. Then I found out that I accidentally added a space during autocomplete between `android.permission.INTERNET` and `"`

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a very confusing kind of bug. There could be many reasons:

1. You are not mentioning the permissions in right place. Like right above application.
2. You are not using small letters.
3. In some case you also have to add Network state permission.
4. One which was my case there are some blank lines in manifest lines. Like there might be a blank line between permission tag and application line. Remove them and you are done. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

**TD;DR**: It also can happens when you are networking from a service that does not have INTERNET permission (In my case I added the permission to the main `:app` but forgot to add to my `:service-module`).

---

Adding my 2 cents here, since this error can happens in any context that leads to a missing internet permission.

I was working with an AIDL, and I had a service which was doing HTTP requests. Then when I was binding this service into my main app I was executing the HTTP method which thrown this error, the thing is: although I added the INTERNET permission into my main app manifest, I forgot to add to my service module, which is actually the process that was executing my HTTP request.

Answer (score -7):

remove this in your manifest file

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Comment: There is no such code in the manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) in the question.