# NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

I am getting the following error:

```
NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

What is causing this error and how can I resolve it? Below is my AndroidManifest.xml file. I am using Volley for network requests.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.my.myfirstandroidapp.app.common.MYApplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.my.myfirstandroidapp.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission)

Comment: tried all solutions in that thread.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define uses-permission tag before application tag. As below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:name="com.my.myfirstandroidapp.app.common.MYApplication">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<activity
    android:name="com.my.myfirstandroidapp.app.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```