# Application crash after false memory allocation exception from /system/lib/libc.so

Tags: android, memory-management, picasso, image-loading

The application has been live round about a year and this problem never came up until the latest upgrades.

After a while from latest updates, especially when the user use "Facebook Login" feature from the App, after receiving the callback, the host application crash with the following false memory allocation exception.

```
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): Build: samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XXUGNA5:user/release-keys
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): Hardware: smdk4x12
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): Revision: 12
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): Bootloader: I9300XXUGNA5
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): Radio: unknown
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): Kernel: Linux version 3.0.31-2429075 (dpi@HP20) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 16 23:47:54 KST 2014
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XXUGNA5:user/release-keys'
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): Revision: '12'
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): pid: 3748, tid: 3859, name: AsyncTask #4  >>> [my application signature] <<<
02-13 13:40:24.560: D/CrashAnrDetector(2346): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     r0 00000001  r1 65a31b7b  r2 0000000f  r3 ffffffff
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 5ccb1065  r7 00000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     r8 5ccb1065  r9 5ccb1065  sl 00000029  fp 5ccb1066
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     ip 5d846b8c  sp 65a31b00  lr 5d82b4b3  pc 40de4b28  cpsr 00000030
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d0  ffffffffffffffff  d1  0000000000000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d2  ffffffffffffffff  d3  ffffffffffffffff
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d4  0000000000000009  d5  0000000000000006
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d6  3f00000042900000  d7  000004000000007f
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d16 4040000000000000  d17 4040000000000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d18 4062000000000000  d19 000d0004000b0003
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d20 0000000400000004  d21 0000000400000004
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d24 0009000000070000  d25 000d0000000b0000
02-12 16:12:58.234: I/DEBUG(18919):     d26 0000000300000002  d27 0000000400000003
02-12 16:12:58.239: I/DEBUG(18919):     d28 0002000000020000  d29 0002000000020000
02-12 16:12:58.239: I/DEBUG(18919):     d30 0001000000010000  d31 0001000000010000
02-12 16:12:58.239: I/DEBUG(18919):     scr 60000090
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919): backtrace:
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919):     #00  pc 00023b28  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_select_next_proto+25)
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919):     #01  pc 000254af  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919):     #02  pc 0002a67f  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+446)
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919):     #03  pc 0001696d  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+904)
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919):     #04  pc 00019457  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+642)
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919):     #05  pc 00024bb9  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+72)
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919):     #06  pc 00029253  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
02-12 16:12:58.249: I/DEBUG(18919):     #07  pc 0001e44c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #08  pc 0004e91b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #09  pc 00027860  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #10  pc 0002be00  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #11  pc 00060a6d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #12  pc 00060a97  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #13  pc 0005582b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #14  pc 0000cb58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #15  pc 0000ccd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919): stack:
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ac0  00000008  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ac4  40865a05  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ac8  00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31acc  580333a0  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ad0  5d82b59d  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ad4  57fddef8  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ad8  00000145  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31adc  408469ab  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_lock+78)
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ae0  4089baa8  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ae4  57fddef8  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31ae8  408c7da8  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31aec  00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31af0  4089baa8  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31af4  40864943  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31af8  df0027ad  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31afc  00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):     #00  65a31b00  5d82b59d  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b04  65a31b7b  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b08  000001ff  
02-12 16:12:58.254: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b0c  65a31b7c  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b10  5bed5168  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b14  ffffffff  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b18  5ccb1065  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b1c  65a31b7b  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b20  65a31b7c  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b24  00003374  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b28  5ccb1065  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b2c  00000001  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b30  5ccb108e  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b34  5d82b4b3  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):     #01  65a31b38  00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b3c  ffffffff  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b40  65a31b7b  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b44  5bed45d0  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b48  65a31bbc  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b4c  5d82b485  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b50  00000029  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b54  40deb681  /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+448)
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):     #02  65a31b58  00000029  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b5c  00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b60  00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b64  5ccb108e  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b68  65a31bb4  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b6c  5ccb108a  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b70  40df3c21  /system/lib/libssl.so
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b74  40df3c21  /system/lib/libssl.so
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b78  00001130  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b7c  00001181  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b80  00001130  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b84  5bed45d0  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b88  0000007a  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b8c  40df7f84  /system/lib/libssl.so
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b90  5ccb1057  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          65a31b94  5ccb1014  
02-12 16:12:58.259: I/DEBUG(18919):          ........  ........
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919): memory near r1:
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b58 00000029 00000000 00000000 5ccb108e  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b68 65a31bb4 5ccb108a 40df3c21 40df3c21  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b78 00001130 00001181 00001130 5bed45d0  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b88 0000007a 40df7f84 5ccb1057 5ccb1014  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b98 00001130 00001181 00001130 40dd7971  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31ba8 65a31bbc 65a31bb8 5bed45d0 5ccb105a  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31bb8 00000001 5bed45d0 5bed45d0 00001120  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31bc8 00001131 00001111 5d82b6b9 40dda45b  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31bd8 ffffffff 5d829e6f ffffffff 54dc6089  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31be8 00000000 5bed45d0 59225270 33500005  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31bf8 46f00009 5991ef18 ffffffff 59206228  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31c08 00000000 40de5bbb 5bed45d0 59225270  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31c18 5bed45d0 5d82f257 00000000 5d84936c  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31c28 00000000 59225270 33500005 0000003b  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31c38 58190dd0 59206218 00000004 59903b88  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31c48 65a31c6c 59903b6c 65a31c84 40b16450  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919): memory near r6:
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1044 a85d95ba 820c5940 2d3be566 cfae92f1  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1054 c0e281ef 32000007 010001ff 00743300  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1064 70730f29 332f7964 662d312e 2e302d62  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1074 70730835 332f7964 7306312e 2f796470  
02-12 16:12:58.269: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1084 74680833 312f7074 0000312e 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919): memory near r8:
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1044 a85d95ba 820c5940 2d3be566 cfae92f1  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1054 c0e281ef 32000007 010001ff 00743300  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1064 70730f29 332f7964 662d312e 2e302d62  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1074 70730835 332f7964 7306312e 2f796470  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1084 74680833 312f7074 0000312e 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919): memory near r9:
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1044 a85d95ba 820c5940 2d3be566 cfae92f1  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1054 c0e281ef 32000007 010001ff 00743300  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1064 70730f29 332f7964 662d312e 2e302d62  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1074 70730835 332f7964 7306312e 2f796470  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1084 74680833 312f7074 0000312e 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919): memory near fp:
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1044 a85d95ba 820c5940 2d3be566 cfae92f1  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1054 c0e281ef 32000007 010001ff 00743300  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1064 70730f29 332f7964 662d312e 2e302d62  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1074 70730835 332f7964 7306312e 2f796470  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1084 74680833 312f7074 0000312e 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb10f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1104 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1114 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1124 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5ccb1134 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919): memory near ip:
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846b6c 405263ed 401625a5 40162459 4016263b  
02-12 16:12:58.274: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846b7c 4015cce1 4085d119 40de5983 40de451f  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846b8c 40de4b0f 4085d1ad 4085cf09 40863549  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846b9c 40828b75 40861749 4085f0dd 4085ee9d  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846bac 4085438d 40857055 40856e69 40858dd1  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846bbc 4085196d 40065b61 4085aa45 4086ae11  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846bcc 40861341 4085b00d 4085aeb9 4085ae6d  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846bdc 4085b2c5 4085d159 4015b055 4085d16d  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846bec 4085cdc1 40de67d9 40de5e41 408469c1  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846bfc 40de573f 4088c021 4083005d 408346a9  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846c0c 4083472f 4088c42d 40837705 4082ee45  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846c1c 40830ed1 4088ba51 40830f01 4088164d  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846c2c 40835815 40838a15 40861815 4086179f  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846c3c 40861fe9 4086200f 40862039 4086202b  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846c4c 40854db1 40854761 40854685 40854e01  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d846c5c 40854789 408543d1 4086ac61 408543dd  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919): memory near sp:
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31ae0 4089baa8 57fddef8 408c7da8 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31af0 4089baa8 40864943 df0027ad 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b00 5d82b59d 65a31b7b 000001ff 65a31b7c  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b10 5bed5168 ffffffff 5ccb1065 65a31b7b  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b20 65a31b7c 00003374 5ccb1065 00000001  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b30 5ccb108e 5d82b4b3 00000000 ffffffff  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b40 65a31b7b 5bed45d0 65a31bbc 5d82b485  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b50 00000029 40deb681 00000029 00000000  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b60 00000000 5ccb108e 65a31bb4 5ccb108a  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b70 40df3c21 40df3c21 00001130 00001181  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b80 00001130 5bed45d0 0000007a 40df7f84  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31b90 5ccb1057 5ccb1014 00001130 00001181  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31ba0 00001130 40dd7971 65a31bbc 65a31bb8  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31bb0 5bed45d0 5ccb105a 00000001 5bed45d0  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31bc0 5bed45d0 00001120 00001131 00001111  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     65a31bd0 5d82b6b9 40dda45b ffffffff 5d829e6f  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919): code around pc:
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b08 30fff04f e92d4770 b0854ff0 469a4616  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b18 24009003 e01e9101 46c89f0e 2000f899  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b28 429a5d7b 1c69d107 18794658 f7e99302  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b38 9b02e94e 1c58b1a8 e006182d 0001f104  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b48 eb062500 eb060904 9b0f0b00 d3e3429d  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b58 1c4a5d31 455418a4 f8ddd3f0 20028038  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b68 2001e000 f1089f03 603a0201 f8989f01  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b78 70391000 e8bdb005 f8d08ff0 600b3178  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b88 e001b903 317cf890 47706013 11a4f8c0  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4b98 21a8f8c0 f8c04770 f8c011ac 477021b0  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4ba8 4604b530 b0856805 7f40f5b5 6884dd0c  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4bb8 9c086e65 9c099400 9c0a9401 9c0b9402  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4bc8 6b6c9403 e00147a0 30fff04f bd30b005  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4bd8 4604b537 447d4d38 d06b2800 738ef240  
02-12 16:12:58.279: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4be8 4b369300 f100220c f04f0060 447b31ff  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     40de4bf8 ef4ef7e8 dc5d2800 00f0f8d4 f7e9b108  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919): code around lr:
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b490 2300461d ee9af7ec f7ff4620 462affe4  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b4a0 6a419b08 46319100 46386a84 f7ec9401  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b4b0 2000ee94 b508bdfe ee94f7ec e8bd2000  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b4c0 f00e4008 b5f7bd65 f7eb4606 ac02ec30  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b4d0 232a2700 f8046805 f7eb3d01 2201ec28  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b4e0 60074621 f7eb68f0 f7ebee3e 6800ec20  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b4f0 d0f22804 ec1af7eb bdfe6005 4610b112  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b500 bd4ef00e b5f84770 68034604 22004615  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b510 781f460e 6800701a 60201b40 edf8f7eb  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b520 68216030 bdf8554f 68186813 bd40f00e  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b530 68186813 bd3cf00e 4610b112 bd40f00e  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b540 b1124770 f00e4610 4770bd43 4610b112  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b550 bd46f00e b5104770 ee6ef7ec f7ec4604  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b560 4284ee72 f7ecd00e 4284ee74 f7ecd00a  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b570 4284ee76 f7ecd006 4284ee78 2002bf0c  
02-12 16:12:58.284: I/DEBUG(18919):     5d82b580 bd102000 bd102001 f7ecb508 2000ee74
```

> The behaviour is not identical in across the devices. 
> Google
>   Nexus 5 : Ok. 
> Samsung S3 : Crash. 
> HTC One+ : App quit
>   without saying anything. 
> Samsung S2 : Ok.

One thing to keep in mind is, because the application is sophisticated media App, the memory usage is around about **150 MB** give or take based on device spec. But, the App doesn't crash with OutOfMemoryException.

The followings are the Q/A that I have checked out.

[SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission)

[Facebook sdk login error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734317/facebook-sdk-login-error?lq=1)

[NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592766/networkdispatcher-run-unhandled-exception-java-lang-securityexception-permissi?lq=1)

I think this issue is relating with [this](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable/issues/70) . But, I am not using this library. I am using Picasso 2.2 for image loading.

Edit :
- Updated Question Title.
- Rule out Facebook SDK.
- Rule out unrelated exception.
- Updated Tags

Comment: A guy also facing the same issue with Picasso sample app and he tried with Picasso version  2.2 >= .
Here is the conversation
https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/550