# Facebook sdk login error

Tags: android

When I am trying to login to facebook from my native android app, I am able to log in and my session object is also "OPENED". But I am getting the user object as null. And in the response, I am getting the following error :

{HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)}

Following is the code snippet :

```
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {

        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            String user_ID = user.getId();//user id
                            String profileName = user.getName();//user's profile name
                        }   
                    }  
                }   
            }); 
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");

        }
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

[what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application).

Comment: Have you read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission

Comment: Also note that you have to put the `android.permission.INTERNET` in the application attributes permission box instead of specifying in the permissions tab (using Eclipse) that your application uses the permission.