# Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?): But permission is given

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to call a httpClient and the response is "Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)". In the normal browser of Android I can open the URL without problems.

```
 public static String getHttpResponse(URI uri) {
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    try {

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
        get.setURI(uri);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);

        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Log.d("demo", "HTTP Get succeeded");

            HttpEntity messageEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = messageEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("demo", e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d("demo", "Done with HTTP getting");
    return response.toString();
}
```

The catch log tell me the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

In my Manifest is the permission set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..." >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: make sure you are mentioning all the permissions out of <application> </application> tag.

Comment: Please change the example of the manifest to the correct one.

Comment: All permission must outside of <application> tag and inside the <menifest> tag.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Did you try giving **permission** above the **application** tag?

You should take care of **order** in which tags are defined in **Manifest.xml.**

See [structure](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct) of Manifest.

**Edited:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    ...>
</application>
```

**Details:**

Order of defining tabs in **Manifest**:

1. Permissions
2. Applications
3. Receiver, Service, Metadata

Answer (score 10):

Permissions must be outside of application tag. So you need to move your permissions outside

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    ... >
</application>
```

---

Read about ***[Structure of the Manifest File](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct)***. The syntax is

```
<manifest>

    <uses-permission />

    <application>
        ....
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

`Permissions` should not be in `Application` `Tag`.. you have to place it as a child for `Manifest`..

Answer (score 2):

Put your user-permission tag above the application tag. Link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..." >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right

```
<uses-permission/>
    <application/>
```

wrong

```
<application>

<uses-permission/>
<application/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
   You give permission correct but Permissions must be outside of the
    application tag  maintain order for the tag

```
  <manifest>
      <uses-permission />
      <application>
       ....
      </application>
      <receiver> </receiver>
      <service> </service>
</manifest>

your code is like this way

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..." >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application> 
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The permissions have to be a direct child of the manifest headings.