# google map not showing in webview on android device

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, webview, android-webview

I am trying to render google map embedded in a webpage through WebView. Though it works on the emulator it's not working on device (android 2.3.6 and 4.4.2). Below is my code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String url = "http://mywebsite.com/mobile_map.php";
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

[image]

1. I tried a direct url and not my webpage as "https://www.google.co.in/maps/@20.3008841,85.7699553,12z?hl=en"
   This also works on AVD but not on devices.
2. Tried to implement an AsysnkTask and also handle the ssl error as follows:

   ```
   public class LoadSocialNetworkUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> { 
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           dialog = new ProgressDialog(MapActivity.this);
           dialog.setMessage("Loading,Please wait...");
           dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
           dialog.setCancelable(true);
           dialog.show();
       }

       protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... url) {
           try {

               ((WebView) webView).getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
               ((WebView) webView).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);  
               ((WebView) webView).setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                       @Override
                       public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                           handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                           // TODO hide your progress image
                           super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                   });

               ((WebView) webView).loadUrl(url[0]);

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               dialog.dismiss();
           }

       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
           try {
               publishProgress(url);

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               dialog.dismiss();
           }   
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

   but the same result.
   What am I missing? Should not we display a page containing map in webview and handle map directly with api? Do I have to make some setting in the device? (the device is connected to internet.)

Comment: Dexter@: Have you declared the INTERNET permission for your app (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135595/permission-denied-missing-internet-permission)? Also, did you try opening other pages (e.g. the main google page) from your app?

Comment: yes, Internet permission added and viewed other page (non map) successfully. Problem is in map pages.

Comment: Well, if you say you can reproduce this problem on Android 4.4.2,  you can try debugging it on that device via remote debugging (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews). Use "Network" tab of DevTools to check what is happening to your requests.

Comment: your wifi connected or data? The image you provided doesn't suggest either of them.

Comment: wifi. The screen shot was taken after wifi is disabled so there is no notification.

Comment: Was there ever any resolution to this? We're encountering the same issue. Try to load a Google map URL in the webview and it's just displaying a blank page on our devices.