# android studio doInBackground Error ModernAsyncTask$.3

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

I am working on an Android Application using Android Studio that uses the http://open-platform.theguardian.com/explore/ API. I am having trouble running the application. I will include some code snippets with the error I am coming across. If anyone needs any additional information to assist please let me know. I appreciate your time in looking at this.

**This is the Error I am running into:**

```html
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
                  Process: com.timothykocik.newsapp, PID: 32631
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:464)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
                      at com.timothykocik.newsapp.QueryUtils.makeHttpRequest(QueryUtils.java:83)
                      at com.timothykocik.newsapp.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:32)
                      at com.timothykocik.newsapp.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:15)
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:299)
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:45)
                      at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                   Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
                      at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
                      at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468) 
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118) 
                      at com.timothykocik.newsapp.QueryUtils.makeHttpRequest(QueryUtils.java:83) 
                      at com.timothykocik.newsapp.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:32) 
                      at com.timothykocik.newsapp.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:15) 
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:299) 
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57) 
                      at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:45) 
                      at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                   Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**This is my QueryUtils Java File:**

```js
public class QueryUtils {

    static String createStringUrl() {
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("http")
                .encodedAuthority("content.guardianapis.com")
                .appendPath("search")
                .appendQueryParameter("order-by", "newest")
                .appendQueryParameter("show-references", "author")
                .appendQueryParameter("show-tags", "contributor")
                .appendQueryParameter("q", "Android")
                .appendQueryParameter("api-key", "test");
        String url = builder.build().toString();
        return url;
    }

    static URL createUrl() {
        String stringUrl = createStringUrl();
        try {
            return new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("Queryutils", "Error creating URL: ", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String formatDate(String rawDate) {
        String jsonDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
        SimpleDateFormat jsonFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(jsonDatePattern, Locale.US);
        try {
            Date parsedJsonDate = jsonFormatter.parse(rawDate);
            String finalDatePattern = "MMM d, yyy";
            SimpleDateFormat finalDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(finalDatePattern, Locale.US);
            return finalDateFormatter.format(parsedJsonDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Error parsing JSON date: ", e);
            return "";
        }
    }

    static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";

        if (url == null){
            return jsonResponse;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.connect();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200){
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e("mainActivity", "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Queryutils", "Error making HTTP request: ", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    static List<News> parseJson(String response) {
        ArrayList<News> listOfNews = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject jsonResults = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
            JSONArray resultsArray = jsonResults.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject oneResult = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String webTitle = oneResult.getString("webTitle");
                String url = oneResult.getString("webUrl");
                String date = oneResult.getString("webPublicationDate");
                date = formatDate(date);
                String section = oneResult.getString("sectionName");
                JSONArray tagsArray = oneResult.getJSONArray("tags");
                String author = "";

                if (tagsArray.length() == 0) {
                    author = null;
                } else {
                    for (int j = 0; j < tagsArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject firstObject = tagsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        author += firstObject.getString("webTitle") + ". ";
                    }
                }
                listOfNews.add(new News(webTitle, author, url, date, section));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Queryutils", "Error parsing JSON response", e);
        }
        return listOfNews;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```js
public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<News>>, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private NewsAdapter adapter;
    private static int LOADER_ID = 0;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipe.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                News news = adapter.getItem(i);
                String url = news.url;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new NewsLoader(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> data) {
        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        if (data != null) {
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            adapter.addAll(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<News>> loader) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }
}
```

Any other additional Information needed please let me know. The app crashes before it can even run on my device. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you include your manifest (especially your permissions section)? I think that that may be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the relevant part of the exception is this:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Please add the following line to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please also see the following questions:

- [What permission do I need to access Internet from an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application)
- [Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?): But permission is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135595/permission-denied-missing-internet-permission-but-permission-is-given)

Comment: Good Lord. Thank you. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you so much for your help. You are a lifesaver.

Comment: I tried hitting the up arrow to accept but it won't accept my check. I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @TimothyKocik The check to accept should be below that