# Permission denied - missing INTERNET permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm having problem with the internet permission. Yes I've looked around and I made sure the permission is outside the application tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.com.example.android.sunshine" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.internet" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here's the logcat:

> 02-13 15:10:07.622    5879-5951/app.com.example.android.sunshine
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: app.com.example.android.sunshine, PID: 5879
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>               at app.com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:117)
>               at app.com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:94)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>        Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
>               at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
>               at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>               at app.com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:117)
>               at app.com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:94)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>        Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>               at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
>               at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>               at app.com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:117)
>               at app.com.example.android.sunshine.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:94)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 02-13 15:15:07.659    5879-5951/app.com.example.android.sunshine I/Process﹕
>   Sending signal. PID: 5879 SIG: 9

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please read here:

[SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission)

Depending on what you are doing you may need to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Official Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Thanks! The capital INTERNET works. It's funny since when I use auto complete with Android studio it gave me lower case.

Answer (score 4):

write it like this (with caps)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

you can also try adding this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Mind the Capital-case. It is "INTERNET"

Answer (score 2):

The permission in question is `android.permission.INTERNET` -- note that case matters.