# Why does my Android app crash on request of permissions?

Tags: android

Whenever I ask for permissions my app crashes. I have the correct uses-permission defined in my manifest as a child of the manifest tag. It doesn't give any error, just a popup saying the Package Installer has stopped and a line in the monitor saying `sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`, which I'm not sure is related to the crash.

Here is the snippet where I ask for permissions:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
    Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.d("MAD", "Internet permission is not enabled!");

    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 
        PERMISSION_REQUEST_INTERNET);

    return null;
}
```

Minimum sdk is set to 23, testing on a Samsung Galaxy S7.

You can see the full code here https://github.com/zimmyg/MAD_Test

Logcat is here:

```
09-18 17:25:05.350 9483-9489/mad.mad_test I/art: Debugger is active
09-18 17:25:05.540 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: Debugger has connected
09-18 17:25:05.540 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:05.730 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:05.930 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:06.130 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:06.330 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:06.530 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:06.740 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:06.940 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:07.130 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
09-18 17:25:07.330 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/System.out: debugger has settled (1339)
09-18 17:25:07.350 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
09-18 17:25:07.380 9483-9483/mad.mad_test W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/mad.mad_test-1/lib/arm64
09-18 17:25:07.500 9483-9483/mad.mad_test W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/mad.mad_test-1/lib/arm64
09-18 17:25:07.520 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
09-18 17:25:07.520 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap mad.mad_test
09-18 17:25:07.520 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/InjectionManager: Constructor mad.mad_test, Feature store :{}
09-18 17:25:07.520 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
09-18 17:25:07.610 9483-9483/mad.mad_test W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/mad.mad_test-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in mad.mad_test rsrc of package mad.mad_test
09-18 17:25:07.620 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
09-18 17:25:07.620 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
09-18 17:25:07.620 9483-9483/mad.mad_test W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/mad.mad_test-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in mad.mad_test rsrc of package mad.mad_test
09-18 17:25:07.750 9483-9483/mad.mad_test W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-18 17:25:07.830 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-18 17:25:07.830 9483-9483/mad.mad_test E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@2d093ce
09-18 17:25:07.830 9483-9483/mad.mad_test E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@a661eda
09-18 17:25:07.830 9483-9483/mad.mad_test E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@a661eda
09-18 17:25:07.840 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
09-18 17:25:07.840 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : mad.mad_test.MainActivity isFragment :false
09-18 17:25:07.870 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
09-18 17:25:07.870 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3d6112e I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
09-18 17:25:07.880 9483-9534/mad.mad_test D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-18 17:25:07.950 9483-9534/mad.mad_test D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f83aff178
09-18 17:25:07.950 9483-9534/mad.mad_test I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                            [ 09-18 17:25:07.960  9483: 9534 D/         ]
                                                            ro.exynos.dss isEnabled: 0
09-18 17:25:07.980 9483-9534/mad.mad_test D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
09-18 17:25:08.090 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :mad.mad_test.MainActivity
09-18 17:25:08.090 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :mad.mad_test.MainActivity
09-18 17:25:08.100 9483-9483/mad.mad_test W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
09-18 17:25:08.110 9483-9534/mad.mad_test D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : mad.mad_test
09-18 17:25:08.200 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
09-18 17:25:08.240 9483-9483/mad.mad_test I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@92514f9 time:304111002
09-18 17:25:18.620 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
09-18 17:25:18.690 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
09-18 17:25:18.700 9483-9800/mad.mad_test D/MAD: Internet permission is not enabled!
09-18 17:25:18.830 9483-9534/mad.mad_test D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7f72b30800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f72b7d7e0
09-18 17:25:18.830 9483-9483/mad.mad_test D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

Comment: please post your log cat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160737/senduseractionevent-mview-null-after-clicking-on-button

Please look at the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016155/senduseractionevent-mview-null-on-samsung-tab3

Comment: @Nas posted logcat

Comment: @AnilPrajapati Those users don't seem to be experiencing crashes. The app crashes immediately after the call to requestPermissions, which is also not referenced in any of those posts.

Comment: None of those logcat messages are errors

Comment: As a quick test, can you comment out the code in your `onRequestPermissionsResult` method and see if the app still crashes.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla It does still crash, I also set a breakpoint inside the onRequestPermissionResult method which never got triggered.

Comment: internet is not a security permission, you can use internet without self permission

Comment: try to look this post how we need to give security permissions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973235/android-permission-denial-starting-intent-with-revoked-permission-android-perm

Comment: @Saveen When I first tried this without asking for permissions it didn't work and the error message suggested that I needed to allow INTERNET permission.

Comment: @ZimGee make sure you have added Internet permission in manifest file

Comment: wait let me check your github code and update it if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i have checked your code and after few updation its working fine for me.Your download url is not working.Also i have added how we can give multiple permission.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<String> entries;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

private ListView listView;
private Button btnStartTest;

//PERMISSIONS
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Marshmallow+
        callMultiplePermissions();
    } else {
        // Pre-Marshmallow
    }
    entries = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, entries);

    listView = (ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnStartTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartTest);
    btnStartTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new BackgroundAsync().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class BackgroundAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Double, Long> {

    private final Integer FILE_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB

    private String current;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        btnStartTest.setEnabled(false);
        current = new String();
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Integer... params) {

            try {
                URL downURL = new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/progressdialog/hive.jpg");
                URLConnection conn = downURL.openConnection();

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long totalDownloaded = 0;

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                int read = 0;
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                while ((read = bis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    totalDownloaded += read;
                    // Publish percentage
                    publishProgress(((double)totalDownloaded/(double)FILE_SIZE) * 100.0);
                }

                long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                return finishTime - startTime;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MAD", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... progress) {
        // Show progress update
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result != null) {
            current = "Speed: " + ((double)FILE_SIZE / 1024 / 1024)/((double)result / 1000) + "MB/s";
            Log.e("MAD","check speed :" + current);
        }
        btnStartTest.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

//************** Multiple permissions ****************//

/**
 * Call multiple Permissions
 */

private void callMultiplePermissions() {
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("NETWORK STATE");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                // Marshmallow+
                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            } else {
                // Pre-Marshmallow
            }

            return;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            // Marshmallow+
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            // Pre-Marshmallow
        }

        return;
    }

}

/**
 * add Permissions
 *
 * @param permissionsList
 * @param permission
 * @return
 */
private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Marshmallow+
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Pre-Marshmallow
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Permissions results
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and others
            if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                // All Permissions Granted

            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
}
```

Added these permissions in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Thanks hope this will help you.

Comment: Thankyou, this seems to work. However, I'm confused as to why I need the write external storage permission, and why I was simply crashing on calling the requestPermissions method before?

Comment: Permission need because somewhere file will download.So, write external storage need to be use.

Answer (score 0):

There is some permission that will be automatically granted at install time and will not be able to revoke. We call it Normal Permission (PROTECTION_NORMAL).

So "android.permission.INTERNET" is under normal permission list, no need to ask permission at run time.

Comment: When I run the app without asking for permissions I get this when I try to get the input stream from my connection: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)`

Comment: Remove the code for checking permission inside doInBackground method.

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: try it with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28510414/1790537

Comment: I tried that as well, it gave the same error. I just pushed again with that change.