# SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) while installing on lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-volley, permission-denied, android-permissions

I am getting the following error:

> NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

What is causing this error and how can I resolve it? Below is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I am using Volley for network requests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rubad.abohaw">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.rubad.abohaw.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not `<user-permission` instead `<uses-permission`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```