# Android - send image to server - Async Task An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: php, android

I want to make an app that takes a picture and sends it to an online server. I have read many tutorials and articles and this is my code so far:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button mTakePhoto;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private static final String TAG = "upload";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        mTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.take_photo:
                takePhoto();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void takePhoto() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + this);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            try {
                sendPhoto(photo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendPhoto(Bitmap bitmap) throws Exception {
        new UploadTask().execute(bitmap);
    }

    private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
            if (bitmaps[0] == null)
                return null;
            setProgress(0);

            Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // convert Bitmap to ByteArrayOutputStream
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert ByteArrayOutputStream to ByteArrayInputStream

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://xxxx/photo.php"); // server

                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                reqEntity.addPart("myFile",
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", in);
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

                Log.i(TAG, "request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (response != null)
                        Log.i(TAG, "response " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
                } finally {

                }
            } finally {

            }

            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.uploaded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume: " + this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    File photoFile = null;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/picupload";
        File dir = new File(storageDir);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdir();

        File image = new File(storageDir + "/" + imageFileName + ".jpg");

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.i(TAG, "photo path = " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }

}
```

MultipartEntity.java

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MultipartEntity implements HttpEntity {

    private String boundary = null;

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    boolean isSetLast = false;
    boolean isSetFirst = false;

    public MultipartEntity() {
        this.boundary = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
    }

    public void writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds(){
        if(!isSetFirst){
            try {
                out.write(("--" + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
            } catch (final IOException e) {

            }
        }
        isSetFirst = true;
    }

    public void writeLastBoundaryIfNeeds() {
        if(isSetLast){
            return ;
        }
        try {
            out.write(("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes());
        } catch (final IOException e) {

        }
        isSetLast = true;
    }

    public void addPart(final String key, final String value) {
        writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();
        try {
            out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +key+"\"\r\n").getBytes());
            out.write("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n".getBytes());
            out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
            out.write(value.getBytes());
            out.write(("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
        } catch (final IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public void addPart(final String key, final String fileName, final InputStream fin){
        addPart(key, fileName, fin, "application/octet-stream");
    }

    public void addPart(final String key, final String fileName, final InputStream fin, String type){
        writeFirstBoundaryIfNeeds();
        try {
            type = "Content-Type: "+type+"\r\n";
            out.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+ key+"\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n").getBytes());
            out.write(type.getBytes());
            out.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n".getBytes());

            final byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
            int l = 0;
            while ((l = fin.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                out.write(tmp, 0, l);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (final IOException e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                fin.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public void addPart(final String key, final File value) {
        try {
            addPart(key, value.getName(), new FileInputStream(value));
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getContentLength() {
        writeLastBoundaryIfNeeds();
        return out.toByteArray().length;
    }

    @Override
    public Header getContentType() {
        return new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChunked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRepeatable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStreaming() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        outstream.write(out.toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public Header getContentEncoding() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void consumeContent() throws IOException,
            UnsupportedOperationException {
        if (isStreaming()) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "Streaming entity does not implement #consumeContent()");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getContent() throws IOException,
            UnsupportedOperationException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.diana.data" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my php:

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "http://xxxx/photos/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);


    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $response['email'] = $email;

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

The problem is that it crashes when it gets to this line and I have no idea why.

```
 response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

This is my logcat:

```
07-14 13:54:26.520  27507-28071/com.example.diana.data E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:441)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:218)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.diana.data.MainActivity$UploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:116)
            at com.example.diana.data.MainActivity$UploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:428)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:218)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.diana.data.MainActivity$UploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:116)
            at com.example.diana.data.MainActivity$UploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:428)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:218)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.diana.data.MainActivity$UploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:116)
            at com.example.diana.data.MainActivity$UploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Any ideas/tips what might be the problem?

Comment: if you have the permission can you post your manifest file please.

Answer (score 4):

As the stacktrace said:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

You need to add the [internet permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) inside your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Another problem is:

```
 Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
```

Probably you need to check the hostname that you are using for sending your request. (http://xxxx/photo.php)

Answer (score 3):

The error specifically tells you that you are missing a permission and that too of internet.

Add the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#) permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Another problem might be that you may be adding the permission incorrectly or if it is not so then you need to check [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission)

Check your host address or You can also try by adding this permission below the internet one:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```