# DownloadManager addCompletedDownload() method not working, gives SecurityException

Tags: android, android-download-manager, securityexception

I am using an url to download and read bytes of data using InputStream, the data thus fetched I am writing using a FileOutputStream in form of a pdf. Then I am using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();`

to write the file in the downloads folder.

The file gets downloaded in the Download folder, and I can access it using FileManager, no issues in that.
But the file does not appear in the Downloads app.
So, I tried by using DownloadManager object

```
mManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

and once the download has happened, I am using

```
mManager.addCompletedDownload(fileName, "Hello", true, "application/pdf", "nn",bufferLength,false);
```

from sources

[addCompletedDownload method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#addCompletedDownload(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20boolean)/)

Now, my first query,

1. I am not quite being able to understand what I must mention for **String path**
2. Using this line of code, I am getting an SecurityException which says 
   **securityexception invalid value for visibility 2 android**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to download a file to the public Downloads directory, it may be easier to use **DownloadManager.enqueue()**

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't want to show the download notification, like in your code, you should add the permission for it in the app manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

SecurityExceptions usualy rised when you dont provide needed permissions.Also maybe this will be helpfull : http://technofaq.org/posts/2014/04/fixing-external-sd-card-write-issue-on-android-kitkat/

Comment: If you are referring to android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, these are already taken care of, but still I don't see any improvement.

Comment: Latest android versions have some permissions bugs see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission

Comment: I hope you already know that you need to add this : <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />