# Stop working Error while getting data from url using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I am an amateur in android programming. I was using Jsoup for getting html from a website and putting it into a textview but I got error. How can I fix this?

**My code:**

```
package com.example.hashtag.asdasd;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Document siteDoc;
    String a;
    Elements p;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new siteGetter().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class siteGetter extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                siteDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://hashtagedu.ir").get();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void displaydata(){
        p = siteDoc.getElementsByTag("p");
        a=p.text();
        TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(a);
    }
}
```

**My Errors:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing
>   INTERNET permission?)
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:464)
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:563)
>                                                                                   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.hashtag.asdasd.MainActivity$siteGetter.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:46)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.hashtag.asdasd.MainActivity$siteGetter.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                                Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed:
>   EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
>                                                                                   at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
>                                                                                   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:563) 
>                                                                                   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540) 
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227) 
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.hashtag.asdasd.MainActivity$siteGetter.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:46) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.hashtag.asdasd.MainActivity$siteGetter.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                                Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed:
>   EACCES (Permission denied)
>                                                                                   at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451) 
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
>                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
>                                                                                   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:563) 
>                                                                                   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540) 
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227) 
>                                                                                   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.hashtag.asdasd.MainActivity$siteGetter.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:46) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.example.hashtag.asdasd.MainActivity$siteGetter.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
>                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Your application doesn't have the`android.permission.INTERNET` permission. You need to add this permission to your app's manifest or ask for it during the app's runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides setting up the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` you currently don't call `displaydata()` and if you do so from your background task, you should set up a handler for invoking the changes on the ui thread:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler uiHandler = new Handler();

    Document siteDoc;
    String a;
    Elements p;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new siteGetter().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    private class siteGetter extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                siteDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://hashtagedu.ir").get();
                displaydata();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void displaydata(){
        p = siteDoc.getElementsByTag("p");
        a=p.text();

        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                tv.setText(a);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Regarding adding a downloaded image (as asked in removed question) to an ImageView (assuming id is `R.id.imageView`)

```
Bitmap bitmap;

public void displaydata(){
    p = siteDoc.getElementsByTag("p");
    a=p.text();
    String imageUrl = siteDoc.select("img").first().attr("abs:src");
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText(a);

            ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must add internet permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: thank you . with this permision my app did't crash but textview can't show the result yet !

Comment: Please vote up this answer and select this answer as result... Thank you.