# Ionic - File upload without reading into memory

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, fileapi

I'm trying to find a way to upload large files without having to read them all into memory.  I need to be able to post multiple files along with a data payload in a single request.  I'm able to accomplish it with standard HTML inputs, something like this:

```html
<input id="myFile1" type="file" />
<input id="myFile2" type="file" />
<input id="myData" type="text" />
```

And javascript code like this:

```js
var file1 = document.getElementById('myFile1').files[0];
var file2 = document.getElementById('myFile2').files[0];
var data = document.getElementById('myData').value;

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('myFile1', file1, file1.name);
formData.append('myFile2', file2, file2.name);
formData.append('myData', data);
```

Even when selecting a large file this is very fast.  Keep in mind I'm only referring to the client side performance, as the actual upload portion is going to be bottlenecked by the users network speed.

So now comes my problem:  I need to use the [Ionic camera plugin](https://ionic.io/docs/premier-plugins/camera) to allow a user to either record video or select video files on their phone.  But when a user picks a file, you aren't immediately given a `File` object to work with; a user picks a file, then you are given a file URL and have to convert that into a `Blob` in order to post it to a server.  However, [as you can see from this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29133446/1745913), you have to read the entire file contents into memory to create the `Blob` object.  This is slow (and very inefficient) when selecting a large file.

Does anyone know of a way to get a `Blob` or `File` object without reading everything into memory?     I looked at the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) and [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) API documentation but from what I see there isn't a way, unless I'm missing something.  I'm wondering how the File API works behind the scenes when using a standard HTML `input` and choosing a file, because as shown by the example above, you're immediately given access to a `File` object (which is also a `Blob`) and it's very fast even for large files.

Comment: you can use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer plugin for large file without loading it into Memory. Take File URI from plugin and pass it to this plugin.

Comment: Here is how you can achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56787887/5909026

Comment: I've looked at that before, but unfortunately the API I'm working with needs the ability to post multiple files along with a data payload in a single request.  I've edited my original question to show this.