# Exception while trying to connect Network

Tags: android

I'm new to Android.

My online app throws exception when I try to connect to any server.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360924/securityexception-permission-denied-missing-internet-permission)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this line to your Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```